# Complete problems for FP

Tags: counting-complexity

Let FP be the class of functions $f : \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ that can be computed in polynomial time. Moreover, given two functions $f : \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ and $g : \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$, we say that there exists a logspace parsimonious reduction from $f$ to $g$ if there exists a function $h :  \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$ such that $h$ can be computed in logspace and $f(x) = g(h(x))$ for every $x \in \{0,1\}^*$.

I would appreciate it if someone could give me some references for problems that are complete for FP under logspace parsimonious reductions (or logspace Turing reductions).

Comment: I should have added that FP-completeness should be under logspace parsimonious or Turing reductions.

Comment: What does "parsimonious" mean in this context? In the context of NP, it means preserving number of witnesses. But in the context of FP, I suppose it could mean a variety of different things...

Comment: I changed the text to make it  more clear, and in particular to explain what I mean by logspace parsimonious reductions.

Comment: For a start, the following is FP-complete: given a constant Boolean circuit with multiple output nodes, compute its output. You may further restrict it to monotone circuits. More generally, if $L$ is any P-complete language (under logspace many-one reductions), then the following problem is FP-complete (under logspace parsimonious reductions): given a sequence of inputs, compute the sequence of bits indicating which of the inputs are in $L$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I think that's an answer (but I think the question may be borderline for cs.SE).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Well, the OP asked for *references*, of which I have offered none.

Comment: @Alejandro: Do you actually want *references*, or you just want some FP-complete problems?

Comment: Thanks for your answers!  Both references and FP-complete problems would be useful.